# Inconsistent ProgressBar style

Tags: discussion, status-completed, android-app

In the majority of the app a blue ProgressBar is being used.

[image: Blue ProgressBar]

In the *Answers* tab, the old (ugly) ProgressBar is being displayed.

[image: Old ProgressBar]

This is inconsistent with the look and feel of the app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fixed in version 0.1.60 coming out later tonight. Note that the screenshot isn't showing a blue circle because you're running Touchwiz and I'm not, but it'll show up correctly in the the color of your theme on your device.

[image]